# Extra argument in call when calling JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData

Tags: swift, swift4

```
let data = json.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let wrapper = JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:nil, error:nil) as NSDictionary
```

**Error is thrown on this line**

```
let wrapper = JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:nil, error:nil) as NSDictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

> what do i do?

Remove the extra argument. The Swift version of the method is declared like this:

```
class func jsonObject(with data: Data, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = []) throws -> Any
```

As you can see, it throws an error instead of taking an error parameter. There's even a sidebar in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1415493-jsonobject) labeled *Handling Errors in Swift:* that explains a bit about how to use this method with `try/catch` to handle errors, and there's a link to more information on the topic.